# GETPIVOTDATA - Create variable to affect multiple - PivotData Formulas

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

If in Excel I have multiple PivotTables that come to a main sheet can I via data validation create a variable in a formula to affect all formulas?

So here is an example of one formula with the day highlighted. I would like to create the day as the variable.

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[IEX_ACW]",'Day Data'!$X$5,"[DateTable].[Day]","[DateTable].[Day].&[Saturday]","[Consultant].[Manager]","[Consultant].[Manager].&[CA Sydney]")
```

i want to be able change

**&[Saturday]**

to

**&[DAY_VARIABLE]**

So that I can change the variable once and affect all Pivottable formulas that link to the one sheet.

Comment: what is the name of your `PivotTable` ? did you set the `PivotTable` to a variable , like `Set PvtTbl = wb1.Worksheets("SheetName").PivotTables("PivotTable 1")` ? if yes it is possible

Comment: I have namee the pivotable in the table design tab. I have 4 PivotTables that go to the main sheet. Named them AHT, CallData, KRA, weekly.

Comment: try changing your line to `=GETPIVOTDATA("[Measures].[IEX_ACW]",'Day Data'!$X$5,"[DateTable].[Day]","[DateTable].[Day]." & DAY_VARIABLE & ,"[Consultant].[Manager]","[Consultant].[Manager].&[CA Sydney]")`